# word2vec - log in the objective softmax function

Tags: nlp, word2vec, mathematics

I'm reading a [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/representation/word2vec#scaling_up_with_noise-contrastive_training) tutorial on Word2Vec models and got confused with the objective function. The base softmax function is the following:

> $P(w_t|h) = softmax(score(w_t, h) = \frac{exp[score(w_t, h)]}{\Sigma_v exp[score(w',h)]}$, where $score$ computes the compatibility of word $w_t$ with the context $h$ (a dot product is commonly used). We train this model by maximizing its log-likelihood on the training set, i.e. by maximizing $ J_{ML} = \log P(w_t|h) = score(w_t,h) - \log \bigl(\Sigma_v exp[score(w',h)\bigr)$

But why $\log$ disappeared from the $score(w_t,h)$ term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the logartihm doesn't disappear. From the equation

[image] ,

When you want to calculate

[image] ,
it essentially means calculating ,  [image]

Now , [image]

So ,

[image]

[image]

as [image].

Comment: So log(exp(x)) log is the natural logarithm I'm I right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That's why log(exp(x)) = x

Answer (score 0):

It's just an optimisation, for the sake of speed and numerical stability. The two are equivalent for the purpose of determining the gradient since log(x) is monotonically increasing with x.